Deriving orthogonality of residuals without normal equation?
In my reading I stumbled across this page which seems to prove the expression for the OLS estimator using the fact that $X^T\hat{\varepsilon} = 0$. However I cannot seem to find a proof of this former fact that doesn't start using the expression we are meant to derive!
In particular, I am looking for:

A justification of the sentence: "because if it wasn’t, there would be another solution $\widetilde{\beta}$ giving another vector $\widetilde{\varepsilon}$ with a smaller residual sum of squares." Why is this?

An appreciation of what it means for the vector of residuals to be orthogonal to the design matrix (i.e. why this is useful, or perhaps a geometric intuition)


Thank you in advance!
Update: In further browsing of the site I found this page which seems to elaborate upon the reasoning. I follow up until (5) which sadly seems to be the important part! Why would $\mathbb{E}[X^T\varepsilon] = 0$ imply $X^T\hat{\varepsilon} = 0$?

Relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515874/why-are-the-residuals-in-mathbbrn-p/516880#516880

Compute the gradient of $\beta \to |y - X\beta|^2$. The gradient being 0 is equivalent to $X^T(y - X\beta) = 0$. If the gradient wasn't 0, $\beta$ is not even the local minimum of $|y - X\beta|^2$, and so there would be another solution $\beta'$ with a smaller residual sum of squares.

This is a standard argument in differential geometry and functional analysis: a critical point of the $L^2$ distance is found via the Pythagorean Theorem, which decomposes the squared distance between a point $y$ and a closed set $\mathcal R={X\beta\mid\beta\in\mathbb R^p}$ into the squared distance orthogonal to $R$ and the squared distance within $R.$

@dummy This is a fine argument, but if you check the link in my post, this fact is deduced from the residuals being orthogonal.

I read the link before my last comment and I do not understand your reply. Your question is why the residuals is orthogonal to design matrix at the minimum. I said it comes from gradient needing to be 0 at the minimum.

@dummy Sorry if I was unclear - the proof of the form of $\hat{\beta}$ I linked in my post starts with the statement that residuals are orthogonal to the design matrix. It then goes on to use this to prove $X^T(y-X\beta)=0$. If this fact were derived through the method you stated then why not simply skip the intermediate step and complete the proof directly?

@Zhanxiong Your post was enlightening as to the implications of the residuals being orthogonal to the design matrix, thank you! However in both proofs it seems you have used the form of the 'hat matrix' to deduce this fact, which if used to complete the linked proof would be circular reasoning, no?

Try viewing the proof in reverse; if you accept the OLS formula for $\hat\beta$, then you can derive the orthogonality of residuals. The OLS formula for $\hat\beta$ doesn't obviously depend on the orthogonality of residuals (i.e., it can be derived as the minimizer of the mean square residual).

@Noah Clearly this is a valid way to derive this fact, however their use of it in this proof implies there is a way not relying on the form of $\hat{\beta}$.

Othogonality can be viewed as a statement that correlation between different residuals is zero. Is this true in general? Probably not, would not be true for beta-regression (where residuals are assumed to follow beta distribution), so I think you will need to assume something.

No, a different "form" for $\hat{\beta}$ wouldn't possess the property; that's what the "Best" in "Best Linear Unbiased Estimator" implies.  An English-language way of looking at it is that if there were a correlation between the residuals and $X$, you could find a different $\hat{\beta}$ that would "explain" part of the residuals, which would, in turn, generate a new set of residuals that would have a smaller squared error.   So your original $\hat{\beta}$ wouldn't be the best one...

Since OLS is BLUE, it must be that there is nothing in the residuals left to explain with a linear model, i.e., the correlation with $X$ equals zero.

@jbowman Of course, this makes sense. I understand why the residuals should be uncorrealated with $X$. However I don't see how this implies that the vector of residuals is orthogonal to the columns of $X$?

"Uncorrelated" = "Orthogonal", they are the same.  Orthogonality of $X$ and $Y$ means that $X'Y = 0$, and $X'Y = 0$ means they are uncorrelated, and vice versa.

@jbowman Ah, I think I see! I was thinking of the theoretical $\varepsilon$ as being independent of $X$, instead of our residuals. Your earlier explanation is intuitive, although I'm unsure why "explaining" the residuals better is guaranteed to reduce the RSS. Would you mind elaborating on this with a mathematical proof?
